# Disable esc key in iframe ANGULAR

Tags: html, angular, iframe

I have an iframe and i need to disable the escape key inside it.

I've already tried it with HostListener, but the listener doesn't work inside the i frame.

i tried something with HostLisntener like this

```
    @HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event'])
    handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      console.log(event)
    }
```

My html

```
   <iframe
      width="100%"
      style="height: calc(100vh - 64px); border: none; "
      #iframe
      [src]="urlIFrame" 
   ></iframe>
```